# Chart.js I want to fix my xAxis to my yAxis position 0

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Here is an example [image]

I currently have this chart structure using chartjs:

```
scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        display: true,
                        labels: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        stacked: true
                    }
                ],
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        type: 'linear',
                        display: true,
                        position: 'left',
                        id: 'y-axis-1',
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        labels: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

[image]

I want my xAxis to be fixed at my yAxis 0 position, I've been googling everything and reading all documentations at: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales without any findings :/

EDIT: Issue posted on chartjs github https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4229

EDIT: Bad news, this is not currently possible, issue is closed and duplicate of
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2950

Comment: Interesting question/requirement. I do not believe this is supported. You could file an issue (questions seem welcome) at https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js and see what the devs have to say about it.

Comment: @xnakos Hi and thanks for your reply, I did post the issue : https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed exactly same, then decided to code it myself, hope it helps someone

Play with css as your use case, comment if you need further help

Note: My chart canvas was required to be wider than its parent container (mobile ;) and it should have a horizontal scroll but ticks were going out of view, now fixed on the left

CSS

```
div#ticks {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 11px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: white;
}
div#ticks > span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    transform: translate(-50%,-2.6px);
    left: 50%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
Chart.prototype.makeTicks = function() {
    var box = this.boxes[3];//This is canvas element with id#y-axis-0
    var lineHeight = (box.bottom-box.top)/(box.ticksAsNumbers.length-1);
    if (this.ticksDiv) {
        this.ticksDiv.remove();
        delete this.ticksDiv;
    }
    this.ticksDiv = document.createElement('div');
    this.ticksDiv.id = 'ticks';
    this.ticksDiv.innerHTML = '';
    this.ticksDiv.style.width = box.width+'px';
    this.ticksDiv.style.height = Math.ceil(box.bottom+2.6)+'px';
    box.ticksAsNumbers.forEach((tick,i)=>{
        var spn = document.createElement('span');
        spn.style.top = (i*lineHeight)+'px';
        spn.innerHTML = tick;
        this.ticksDiv.appendChild(spn);
    });
    this.canvas.parentNode.insertBefore(this.ticksDiv,this.canvas);
}
```

then

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [{
        afterLayout: function(chart) {
            chart.makeTicks();
        }
    }],
    ...
```